# How to get/inject EPartService outside part or in LifeCycle Manager or How to control life cycle of e4 RCP app in true sense?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

My application consists of many parts and they are defined in application's e4xmi file. I want to hide and show them dynamically. I am using EpartService to do so in handlers, where I can inject it.

But I also want to control the show/hide of parts with something like life cycle manager, where I can not inject EPartService. Is there any way to achieve and fully control RCP application's life cycle?

There seems the exact same question here and void of solution: 
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/595958/

I want to implement 'remember me like feature' where part having sign in screen is shown instead of other parts. Also after log out same sign-in part is to be shown. So I need to control life cycle of RCP app. But I cant inject EPartService before anything in Application's e4xmi is initiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating a class from something which is injected (such as the LifeCycle class) you can create your class with injection using `ContextInjectionFactory`:

```java
@Inject
IEclipseContext context;


MyClass myClass = ContextInjectionFactory.make(MyClass.class, context);
```

Or if you just pass an `IEclipseContext` to the class you can get the part service using:

```java
EPartService partService = context.get(EPartService.class);
```

Note: There is a separate instance of the part service for each part. Depending on what you are doing you may need to make sure you have the service for the active part.

Comment: Sir, I have LifeCycle Manager. In its  PostContextCreate method the EPartService is null. My question is how can i decide which part to show when the splash screen is being shown.

Comment: `@PostContextCreate` is too early, if you are running the splash screen from there you can't get the services you need. The part service will be set in the `@ProcessAdditions` method of the LifeCycle. Or subscribe to the `UIEvents.UILifeCycle.APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE` event.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not locked in to using SWT, you could use the e(fx)clipse e4 renderer for JavaFX instead.

e(fx)clipse has more possibilities to control the lifecycle of the application. For example you can return a `Boolean` from `@PostContextCreate` to signal whether you want to continue the startup or not. You will not be able to use `EPartService` here though, but you can roll your own login dialog using dependency injection as greg-449 has described it in his answer.

```java
public class StartupHook {

    @PostContextCreate
    public Boolean startUp(IEclipseContext context) {
        // show your login dialog
        LoginManager loginManager = ContextInjectionFactory.make(LoginManager.class, context);
        if(!loginManager.askUserToLogin()) {
            return Boolean.FALSE;
        }
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }

}
```

(You can also restart the application. Form
 more details see http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2014/11/03/efxclipse-1-1-new-features-api-to-restart-your-e4-app-on-startup/).